# Is there a way to check if code is run durring org export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When exporting org to pdf (LaTeX) I want to export plots as pdf, while the preview inside emacs should be exported to png. I am currently using a function for generating the export path already. This function should be able to detect if exporting, and if so, change the file extension (as emacs can not display inline PDF).

I am using it like this:

```
#+begin_src gnuplot :file (org-babel-tmp-file)
...
```

where `org-babel-tmp-file` generates a file path using a uuid.

I am looking for something like `(is-org-export-p)`.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you show the "function for generating the export path already"? How  and where is it to be used?

Comment: Yes, I am using it like this: `#+begin_src gnuplot :file (org-babel-tmp-file)` where `(org-babel-tmp-file)` generates a file path using a uuid.

Comment: I see - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable `org-export-current-backend`. It is set to the current backend during export, so you can check *which* backend is used as well. Read its doc string with `C-h v org-export-current-backend`:

```
Its value is a symbol such as ‘html’, ‘latex’, ‘ascii’, or nil if
the back-end is anonymous (see ‘org-export-create-backend’) or if
there is no export process in progress.

It can be used to teach Babel blocks how to act differently
according to the back-end used.
```

The last paragraph is particularly apt, given your question. Note that the value of the variable is a *symbol*, not a string.

EDIT: In this case, there was an existing variable, but @TianshuWang's answer would be useful if there was *no* existing variable and you wanted to pass information from the top-level export function down to the lower level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is a better way, you can advice `org-export` function and make a flag like:

```lisp
(defun org-export@around (fun &rest r)
  (let ((org-export-p t))
    (apply fun r)))
(advice-add 'org-export :around #'org-export@around)
```